# How to upgrade pg_dumpall

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, postgresql-9.3, centos7

I am trying to migrate from Postgres 9.3 to 9.4, and I would like to run:

```
pg_dumpall > outfile.sql
```

But, I keep getting this error:

```
server version: 9.3.10; pg_dumpall version: 9.2.13
aborting because of server version mismatch
```

I found `pg_dumpall` here: `/usr/bin/pg_dumpall`

I found an answer saying to do this:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump --force`

But in **Centos**, this is the output for this directory:

`sudo ls /var/lib/pgsql/9.3`

Output:

*backups  data  initdb.log*

Does anyone know how to upgrade **pg_dumpall** to match the postgres version in Centos 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS has its own disk layout.  I'd expect your 9.3 `pg_dump` will be in:

```
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_dump
```

You can look for `pg_dump` files on your filesystem with:

```
find / -name pg_dump -executable -print
```

Comment: Andomar, your path's and `find` command worked perfect.  Thank you.  The only other thing I did (which was the same process) was to symlink `pg_dumpall`like so: `sudo ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_dumpall /usr/bin/pg_dumpall --force`.  Cheers, thank you.